# Loading next Screen/ ApplicationWindow from Qt quick control 2

Tags: android, c++, qt, qtquickcontrols2

I am very new to the Qt quick control 2 development. I am developing one cross platform application for android. I am loading new screen from c++ code as bellow

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

{

```
QApplication app(argc, argv);

QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

CommunicatorClass mCommunication;

engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("CommunicatorClass", &mCommunication);

engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

QObject *topLevel = engine.rootObjects().value(0);

QQuickWindow *window = qobject_cast<QQuickWindow *>(topLevel);

window->show();

return app.exec();
```

}

This loads my Sign In screen. Once user submits Username,Password application is verifying same in c++ code. Hence communication between qml to c++ is working fine. Now i want to load next screen when username and password gets validated. please guide me how to proceed in this case as i am very new to both c++ and qt quick control 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to have a property on the object exported from C++ that refers to the "current screen".
The code in main.qml can then use a `Loader` to load that screen.

That will look a bit like this in C++:

```
class CommunicatorClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QString currentScreen READ currentScreen NOTIFY currentScreenChanged);

public:
    QString currentScreen() const;
signals:
    void currentScreenChanged();
};
```

In QML somewhat like this:

```
Window {
    Loader {
        source: CommunicatorClass.currentScreen
    }
}
```

assuming that the `currentScreen` property refers to a QML file relative to main.qml